# Allow posting images even for new users, when the question would benefit from it

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, new-users, images

Currently new users aren't allowed to post images. This ban was implemented for fear of spammers, and later justified by noting that it actually cut down on screenshots of code and other text.

As an unfortunate result, we see that many questions that are actually about image processing fail to include problematic input and/or output. This is a situation we can detect from keywords in the title, or from tags. E.g. "OpenCV" is a strong hint that images are in fact appropriate.

Thus, the feature request: allow new users to post an image, even if they don't have sufficient rep, when they do use specific keywords and tags.

Suggested list of excepted tags:

- image-processing
- image-manipulation
- image-recognition
- computer-vision
- opencv
- emgucv
- javacv
- aforge
- imagemagick
- python-imaging-library

Note: the abuse potential is theoretically present, as spammers might discover this feature. OTOH, this feature isn't easily discovered by drive-by spammers, as their posts are unlikely to contain the necessary tags. Spammers who do understand SO typically wouldn't be hindered by the image post restrictions anyway.

Comment: Fair point. Spam without images gets destroyed within 30 seconds. Spam *with* images will, too. What's the problem?

Comment: I'd be more worried about trolling than spamming. e.g. someone posting NSFW images.

Comment: Spam isn't the core problem, newbie SO users are apt to post a screenshot instead of describing their problem properly.  Straight from their text editor :(

Comment: @HansPassant: I know, see my first sentence. But the typical OpenCV user differs from the typical Javascript or PHP newbie, which is why I'm suggesting to make it tag-dependent.

Answer (score 13):

What generally happens is that if someone (more likely a 2k+ user) looks at the post, if they feel it's a reasonable question that would benefit from the image, they'll edit it to add it.

There's probably corner cases where this restriction isn't necessary but I doubt they're really worth special casing via tags/other criteria.

It's really not difficult to get enough rep to post an image - even for a completely new user that's posted an interesting question - they'll have it added for them or a couple of upvotes later, be able to add it themselves.

Comment: I know, I've been doing precisely this. But as a software engineer, I feel the instinctive need to automate repeated tasks.

Comment: @MSalters I'm all for automation where appropriate but with shed loads of people actively monitoring/reviewing and trying to better the site (the ethos that the SE sites were built upon) - how would one special case this?

Comment: Well, obviously the restriction itself is already a special case as most users can in fact images. So, you'd add a further limitation to the restriction: not only must the user be < 10 rep, but in addition neither the tag list nor the title may contain any terms from that list. As a nice-to-have, when those terms _are_ detected in a post for a low-rep user,_do_ suggest that they add images to describe their problem.

Comment: @MSalters: Well, are you really sure you want those tags overrun with image-spam, goatse and the like?

Answer (score 9):

I'm going to say this is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) based on a recent [implementation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). We've made a change that will *sort of* allow [new users < 10 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user) to post images.

If a user hasn't hit the required rep to post images, we will automatically include a link to the image instead of blocking them.  This will allow the images to be included in the post, but won't prevent the post from being added. Users with less than 10 rep (the new user privilege) will now see the following message when they try to post an image.

First, the image uploaded will show:

> [image]

Second, if they don't have > 10 rep, they will see:

[image]

They will no longer be blocked from posting an image, it will just be converted to a link if they don't have the required rep.